# What type of declaration is this? a function? class?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I was looking at code in node.js, express, mongoose. It is defining a schema:

```
var Comment = new Schema({
    username : String,
    content  : String,
    created  : Date
});
```

I do not understand what this actaully is, because

```
var Comment =
```

Is like a function/variable

```
new Schema
```

is like a class
and

```
    {
        username : String,
        content  : String,
        created  : Date
    }
```

is like an associative array...

What exactly is this type of block? and how does it work?

Thanks a lot

Comment: That's a schema of a collection

Comment: it's a call to a constructor passing an anon object populated with globals that returns an object.

Comment: Without knowing the details you simply assign an instance of `Schema` to `Comment`. The literal object is an argument for the `Schema` constructor. What is it that you don't understand particularly? There's nothing out of the ordinary in this syntax other than the object constructors `String`, `Date`, etc...

Comment: you have answered my question already! perfect and thank you! + 1

Answer (score 1):

This is the object-oriented style of JavaScript, especially the concept of model-view controller.

What you describe in your examples here is called a model. It defines how the data which are put in and out fit into the concept.

So this model would be named comment and it would hold username, content as strings and created as date. It would be easily saveable to a database later by calling e.g.

```
Comment.save();
```

"new Schema" tells the engine here that a new model should be created.

Please see also here:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html